# Why aren't I getting 64 bit warnings in Visual Studio 2012 unless I turn on a "deprecated" compiler switch?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, warnings

I recently came across a 64 bit compatibility bug in our code where a 64 bit pointer was being stored in a 32 bit number and had ended being used causing an access violation.  The bug had been in our code for 2 years!  We had somehow never crashed until recently when we changed to the VC2012 C-runtime when it started crashing all the time.  I was curious as to why we'd never seen a compiler warning for this.  I created the following program and turned on `/W4` on the VC2012 compiler.  I built it in 64-bit mode.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    void* b = new int;
    ULONG ulB = (ULONG)b;
    return 0;
}
```

This program compiled without warnings however, when I turned on /Wp64 I saw this warning:

```
1>cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'Wp64' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
1>ConsoleApplication5.cpp(10): warning C4311: 'type cast' : pointer truncation from 'void *' to 'ULONG'
```

.. which is the kind of thing I expected.

When I looked at the documentation I see that `/Wp64` has indeed been deprecated.  However, it's supposed to now be built into the standard `/W4` warning set and the page says "Instead of using this option and keyword to detect 64-bit portability issues, use a Visual C++ compiler that targets a 64-bit platform and specify the `/W4` option"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt4xw8fh(v=vs.110).aspx

So what gives?  `/W4` does not produce 64-bit warnings in the same way as the old deprecated `/Wp64` does...

Comment: Sounds more like a bug. Did you install the VS service packs? And its completely unrelated but, VS2012 don't support C++11, I recommend upgrading so you can start using the new stuff. And perhaps they fixed this bug there.

Comment: I have VC2013 too, similar deal on that platform.  No warning is printed for that cast on /W4.

Comment: Interesting...  if I turn on "all warnings" I do start getting the 64 bit warning again.  So it looks like the documentation is wrong.  The only way to get them is to go above /W4.  Unfortunately that's impracticable since turning on "all warnings" means that our build produces thousands of warnings all from the Windows header files..

Answer (score 1):

So the answer appears to be not all 64-bit warnings are available in `/W4`.  However if you want to catch this particular type of bug you should build with `/w14302` which switches warning 4302 to level 1.  Hence it'll be printed out in a normal build without having to turn on all warnings.